# Wordpress Adding Custom HTTP Header To One Template File

Tags: php, wordpress, http-headers

I need to add a header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` into one of my template files. How would I do this I would like it to be for just this specific template so that its not site wide,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for is_page_template();

```
<?php 
if(is_page_template('your-page-template.php')) { //Change this to the path to your wordpress template
    //Add your code here...
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a custom template page and call the custom Header on this template. 
To create a page and apply a page template

use this code to create page template

Answer (score -1):

First you need to have a single page. There are several ways to do it, one is to create a page in wordpress, then use the ID and create a file page-ID.php in the theme folder. Other way is to create a template file which you can select from the side menu in the wordpress editor.

In that page, you can add the php header and the code you want to show.